# How can I have my Twitter card expanded by default?

Tags: twitter

[This tweet](https://twitter.com/wpelevation/status/448142283654041601) is expanded by default in [this timeline](https://twitter.com/wpelevation/).

[My tweet](https://twitter.com/Whonix/status/448481030878404608) here is not expanded by default in [my timeline](https://twitter.com/Whonix/). (The [Twitter card validator](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator) does not show any errors for my tweet.)

How can I have my Twitter cards expanded by default as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two is that the expanded one includes an image uploaded to Twitter.

Both might have links to webpages with valid Twitter card meta data, but when a tweet includes an [image uploaded to pic.twitter.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55211/some-images-show-automatically-on-the-twitter-timeline-others-do-not) (and not just to any image hosting) then it will show a portion of that image in the timeline.